# How to sketch the region described by transformed random variables U and V

Tags: probability, integration, limits, graphing-functions, density-function

I have the following question, for which the first part of (a), I had no trouble with, however, when it comes to sketching the region described (highlighted in yellow) - problem is in the link further below. I'm a bit lost on how to even approach this.

for context and to know that I haven't just run here, I have watched several videos which I thought would help on sketching the range. However, none have worked, and this is not covered in any of my lectures, which makes me assume this is considered a pre-requisite, which unfortunately I don't have in my background or don't recall.

I have spent over a day looking for a way on how to tackle this and the most relevant content I found is the Youtube video below, however, this was a F_x(x), rather than a joint pdf, and going from one to the other doesn't seem like something I should take for granted or assume is too easy - also, I can't be 100% certain this is the correct track, but I think so.

video I tried:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vf7ER2GSenI

Could someone please advise how to approach this problem...

[THE MATH PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7cvY.jpg)

Thank you very much for the help!
It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

$$\begin{cases}
u=xy   \\
v=\frac{x}{y} 
\end{cases}\rightarrow\begin{cases}
x=\sqrt{uv}   \\
y=\sqrt{\frac{u}{v} }
\end{cases}$$

it is self evident that it must be also

$$\begin{cases}
1\leq uv<+\infty ,& (1)  \\
1\leq \frac{u}{v} <+\infty,&(2)
\end{cases}$$

Plotting this region in the 1st Quadrant of Cartesian Axes you get the requested solution

[image]

In fact (1)is satisfied under the condition $u\geq \frac{1}{v}$ while (2) is satisfied when $u\geq v$

When $v\in (0;1)$ the first condition (1) is stronger, when $v>1$ is the second one (2) to be the strongest

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your answer, I understand how X = sqrt of UV, I arrived at the same answer.but how does Y = sqrt of u/u  ? that doesn't add up to me, I would have throught Y = V / sqrt(UV).

Comment: @Fraf:  come on guy....u/u....it's an evident typo...amended

Comment: Please forgive me, I was just pedantic for the sake of ensuring I'm not taking anything for granted and learning from this as properly as possible.

Thank you for the help!  I will definitely be checking this answer.

Comment: @Fraf:  in the meantime I added some detail for you understanding. Check my solution and let me know if it is clear enough...and welcome to the site